# Converting a VB code to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, bluetooth

I've been struggling to understand this VB code, I'm trying to build a application that uses Bluetooth connection for communication, can anyone please help me to convert ti to C# so I can understand it properly.

```
    ' The host part of the URI is the device address, e.g. IrDAAddress.ToString(),
' and the file part is the OBEX object name.
Dim addr As String = "112233445566"
Dim uri As New Uri("obex://" & addr & "/HelloWorld.txt")
Dim req As New ObexWebRequest(uri)
req.ReadFile("Hello World.txt")
Dim rsp As ObexWebResponse = CType(req.GetResponse(),ObexWebResponse)
Console.WriteLine("Response Code: {0} (0x{0:X})", rsp.StatusCode)



    ' The host part of the URI is the device address, e.g. IrDAAddress.ToString(),
' and the file part is the OBEX object name.
Dim addr As String = "112233445566"
Dim uri As New Uri("obex://" & addr & "/HelloWorld2.txt")
Dim req As New ObexWebRequest(uri)
Using content As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
   ' Using a StreamWriter to write text to the stream...
   Using wtr As New StreamWriter(content)
      wtr.WriteLine("Hello World GetRequestStream")
      wtr.WriteLine("Hello World GetRequestStream 2")
      wtr.Flush()
      ' Set the Length header value
      req.ContentLength = content.Length
   End Using
   ' In this case closing the StreamWriter also closed the Stream, but ...
End Using
Dim rsp As ObexWebResponse = CType(req.GetResponse(),ObexWebResponse) 
Console.WriteLine("Response Code: {0} (0x{0:X})", rsp.StatusCode)



    Dim lsnr As New ObexListener(ObexTransport. Bluetooth)
lsnr.Start()
' For each connection
Dim ctx As ObexListenerContext = lsnr.GetContext()
Dim req As ObexListenerRequest = ctx.Request
Dim pathSplits() As String = req.RawUrl.Split('/')
Dim filename As String = pathSplits(pathSplits.Length – 1)
req.WriteFile(filename)
'
lsnr.Stop()




    Dim addr As BluetoothAddress _
  = BluetoothAddress.Parse("001122334455")
'
Dim ep As New BluetoothEndPoint(addr, BluetoothService.SerialPort)
Dim cli As New BluetoothClient
cli.Connect(ep)
Dim peerStream As Stream = cli.GetStream()
peerStream.Write/Read ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using an online converter?

Comment: What have you tried? maybe look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910022/bluetooth-file-send)

Comment: Are there any specific parts you don't understand? There does not seem to be any fancy stuff in there...

Comment: there are available tools for conversion. Like SharpDevelop

Comment: I didn't know they exist. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone y'll been very helpful1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply paste in your VB.NET code , and this free utility will automatically convert it to its equivalent in C#.

Just go through [VB.Net to C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

or any other online code translator. [VB.Net -> C#](http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/)

Hope it will help you.