# Need convert this code to vb

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do I convert this c# code to VB code?

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (Session["Lang"] != null)
        {
            string selectlang = Session["Lang"].ToString();
            Culture = selectlang;
            UICulture = selectlang;
        }
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would be the first question springs up to my mind, yes why?

Comment: I wonder, Why dint you even try [this](http://goo.gl/XXz6XC) ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a VB code to C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945209/converting-a-vb-code-to-c-sharp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Public Class BasePage
    Inherits Page
    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        If Session("Lang") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim selectlang As String = Session("Lang").ToString()
            Culture = selectlang
            UICulture = selectlang
        End If
        MyBase.InitializeCulture()
    End Sub
End Class
```